# Postgres extension create

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

When I am trying to create extension

```
cms=# CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory
```

I am getting this error and when I searched for extension they are in 
`/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension` directory.

I have multiple server installed in my local machine.

How to overcome this problem so that I can create extensions?

Comment: do you have `contrib` package installed?

Comment: yes when i am trying to install it says this-Package postgresql93-contrib-9.3.9-1PGDG.f21.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: and what does `show server_version;` in `psql` say?..

Comment: server_version 
----------------
 9.3.9
(1 row)

Comment: what does `sudo find / -name uuid-ossp.control` in `shell` say?..

Comment: /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension/uuid-ossp.control

Comment: yes, thats work thanks. i have just copy contrib/uuid-ossp/uuid-ossp* file to /usr/lib/postgresql-bdr/share/extension/ and then i copy 9.4 version /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/uuid-ossp.so to /usr/lib/postgresql-bdr/lib/ i have not symbolic link this i have done on centos6.4 with BDR multi master and postgres9.4

Answer (score 0):

you need symbolic link then

`sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension /usr/share/pgsql/extension`

Comment: after creating soft link I am getting this error cms=# CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory

Comment: please can u help me on how to do it..is it like this--psql -U username databasename -f /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension/uuid-ossp--1.0.sql

Comment: I deleted manual extension creation from my answer. The idea was bad :) what are ownership and permissions on both `/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension ` and `/usr/share/pgsql/extension` ?..

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root for /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension and [mohit@ARW-MUM-WK-1575 ~]$ ls -l /usr/share/pgsql/extension
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Aug 27 14:15 /usr/share/pgsql/extension -> /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension/

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 163 Jun 11 16:59 /usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control

Comment: is it something to do with multiple postgres server installed in my machine

Comment: because when i am doing this yum list installed | grep postgres
postgresql.x86_64              9.3.9-1.fc21       updates                    
postgresql-libs.x86_64        9.3.9-1.fc21      updates                    
postgresql-server.x86_64   9.3.9-1.fc21      updates                    
postgresql93.x86_64     9.3.9-1PGDG.f21    pgdg93                     
postgresql93-contrib.x86_64 9.3.9-1PGDG.f21    pgdg93                     
postgresql93-libs.x86_64  9.3.9-1PGDG.f21  pgdg93                     
postgresql93-server.x86_64       9.3.9-1PGDG.f21    @pgdg93

Answer (score 0):

Actually issue was that my *.so files were in /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib and in pg_config file /usr/lib64/pgsql path was given so I just copied all files from /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib to /usr/lib64/pgsql.

Also I created a softlink sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension /usr/share/pgsql/extension .By doing these two things my issue is resolved.

Thanks everyone for your support.